# Java Local Nested Classes and accessing super methods

Tags: java, class, nested, super

I have following class hierarchy scenario; Class A has a method and Class B extends Class A, where I want to call a method from super class from a locally nested class. 
I hope a skeletal structure picture the scenario more clearly
Does Java permit such calls?

```
class A{
  public Integer getCount(){...}
  public Integer otherMethod(){....}
}

class B extends A{
  public Integer getCount(){
    Callable<Integer> call  = new Callable<Integer>(){
      @Override
      public Integer call() throws Exception {
         //Can I call the A.getCount() from here??
         // I can access B.this.otherMethod() or B.this.getCount()
         // but how do I call A.this.super.getCount()??
         return ??;
      }
   }
    .....
  }
  public void otherMethod(){
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure you want to call overridden method implementations of the outer class from an inner class? Seems like a right mess to me.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - I believe that this is properly a "local anonymous" class not an "inner" class - which makes it that much more of a mess.

Comment: @emory Technically, anonymous inner classes are local classes are inner classes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just use `B.super.getCount()` to call `A.getCount()` in `call()`.

Answer (score 5):

You've to use `B.super.getCount()`

Answer (score 4):

Something along the lines of

```
package com.mycompany.abc.def;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

class A{
    public Integer getCount() throws Exception { return 4; }
    public Integer otherMethod() { return 3; }
}

class B extends A{
    public Integer getCount() throws Exception {
        Callable<Integer> call  = new Callable<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                   //Can I call the A.getCount() from here??
                   // I can access B.this.otherMethod() or B.this.getCount()
                   // but how do I call A.this.super.getCount()??
                   return B.super.getCount();
            }
       };
       return call.call();
    }   
    public Integer otherMethod() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

perhaps?